# How to showing report that group by archieve with PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to recapitulate report that grouped by month. But the results of sum is incorrect. It's just sum data in one month and show in all rows.

```
<?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barang GROUP BY arsip");

                $i = 1;

            while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            ?>
            <tr class="<?php if ($i % 2 == 0) { echo "odd"; } else { echo "even"; } ?>">
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['arsip']; ?></td>



                <td><?php 
                $Masuk= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(barang_in) AS masuk FROM barang GROUP BY arsip");

                if($Masuk){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($Masuk);
  echo $data['masuk'];
    }
                ?></td>

                <td><?php 
                $keluar= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out) AS keluar FROM barang GROUP BY arsip");

                if($keluar){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($keluar);
  echo $data['keluar'];
    }?></td>

                <td><?php 
                $efisiensi= mysql_query("SELECT SUM((bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out)-barang_in) AS efisiensi FROM barang GROUP BY arsip");

                if($efisiensi){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($efisiensi);
  echo $data['efisiensi'];
    }
                ?></td>

                <td><?php 
                $persen= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(barang_in/(bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out))*1 AS persen FROM barang GROUP BY arsip");
                $simbol = "%";

                if($persen){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($persen);
  echo number_format($data['persen'],2); echo $simbol;
    }
                ?></td>





            <?php 
            $i++;
}

            ?>
```

so that's my code. what's wrong with that? There are some columns for displaying income items, outcome items, efficiency ( difference of outcome and income items ) and percent of efficiency.

Comment: Why do you run this second query `SELECT distinct archieve AS arsip FROM report`?

Comment: I use distinct because I just found out that distinct it used to prevent showing double of that data. So what should I do? delete that part? Because I make one column to show name of month in archieve's column.

Comment: i think group by archieve in your first query will do that

Comment: hey, Great it works for column "Archieve". But I still have 4 columns that use to show "Incoming Items", "Out Items", "Items Efficiency" and "Percent of Efficiency" and they're still error.

Comment: I would like to recapitulate the sum of these items each month, but results count that appears are incorrect. I want that recapitulate's result show appropriate with months. That's why I grouped it into archive.

Comment: @ulaaaan Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Nobody will ever frown at you for not writing English perfectly, but please put some time and effort in formatting your questions. See my edit? This is much easier to read, don't you think? Feel free to edit again if you don't like it this way, this is your question after all.

Comment: @Strawberry I just use 1 table for this. Can you give me example how to use join with one table? As I know, join is use when we have different table hmm.

Comment: @RandomSeed okay wait a moment.

Comment: You would need to create an alias for each instance of the table - although you may not need a join in this instance - but I don't understand why you think you need 4 queries instead of just one!

Comment: @RandomSeed I just edited my post, is it clear enough? I need help, really.

Comment: Your whole approach is incorrect. You should rather aim at writting a better SQL query. I am not sure I get the full picture, but I am convinced you could fetch your whole report data in **just one query**, then iterate over the result set in order to format it to HTML. Please provide a description of the relevant tables in your database. I think the cornerstone is this `archieve` field. What is it? Presumably the achive *date*, right?

Comment: I'm using name of month to classify. Is it possible to use just one query? how to format it into HTML? tell me, please. In this case, I have 4 columns and wanna to fill it with archive, total of income items, outcome of income items and efficiency. Efficieny is difference of outcome items and incoming items. @RandomSeed

Comment: What is "name of month"? Is it the `archieve` field?

Comment: Sorry my last comment was misleading. By "formatting to HTML" I was referring to nothing special but the method you already take (i.e. loop through a result set and insert HTML tags), but I'm sure this can be done by parsing just one SQL query result set.

Comment: @RandomSeed yaaap, I'm use like "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014" for Archieve.

Comment: @RandomSeed if I use one query, it will like this :

SELECT archieve, SUM( barang_in ) AS Income, SUM( bijih_out + htm_out + pth_out ) AS Outcome, SUM( (
bijih_out + htm_out + pth_out
) - barang_in ) AS Efficiency, SUM( (
barang_in / ( bijih_out + htm_out + pth_out ) ) *1
) AS Percent
FROM items
GROUP BY archieve

. It shows correct results if I do that in mySQL. How to apply that into columns?

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14430366/1446005), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18172740/1446005), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9386295/1446005), and many more! There are plenty of code samples that will help you.

Comment: @RandomSeed yes I got it, and my code is work now. Thankyou very much ya hehe :D

Comment: Glad this helped. You may want to post your final code *as an answer* and accept it, as it could help future visitors.

Comment: @RandomSeed yep, already written ;D

Comment: @ulaaaan This is not really the right way to proceed. We expect questions be, well, questions :) Scroll down to the bottom of the page: see the "Post your answer" button? This is how answers should be provided. Thanks for your feedback anyways!

Comment: Please kindly take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and check the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/help) ([this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), for instance)

Comment: @RandomSeed oh yeah sorry, I just edited that, thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

finally I found out the right code. Thankyou for @RandomSeed who helps me. This is my final code and it works!

```
<?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT arsip, SUM(barang_in) AS income, SUM(bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out) AS outcome, SUM((bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out
)-barang_in) AS efficiency, SUM((barang_in / ( bijih_out + htm_out + pth_out))*100) AS percent FROM barang GROUP BY arsip");

                $i = 1;

            while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            ?>
            <tr class="<?php if ($i % 2 == 0) { echo "odd"; } else { echo "even"; } ?>">
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['arsip']; ?></td>



                <td><?php echo $data['income']; ?></td>


                        <td><?php echo $data['outcome']; ?></td>


                <td><?php echo $data['efficiency']; ?></td>

                <td><?php $simbol = "%"; echo number_format($data['percent'],0); echo $simbol; ?></td>





            <?php 
            $i++;
}

            ?>
```